# CSS3 PIE (rounded corners) in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css, xhtml, css3pie

Hello i have problem with CSS3 PIE in all IE with rouned corners. In Opera, Firofox, Chrome etd... my code works as it should. But in IE not. I don´t know why. Logically I tried found reason on internet.
I tried:
1. Add ".htaccess" with this code "AddType text/x-component .htc" but I use include PIE.php and with this include I don´t need this file because in PIE.php I have include on PIE.htc .
2. I tried add relative positions to div, which uses PIE and to his "father" as I found in [css3pie.com](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/) but nothing new.

Here is link to test page (I test it on localhost i IE7-9 and in IETester in IE6-IE9): [link](http://asasini.own.cz/_test/slash_home.php)

Thanks for answers and sorry for my english.

**UPDATE 14.02.2013 (SOLVED)** 
- I am big lame problem is in "behavior" where I use incorrect link to PIE.php (why .php and "not .htc" read on top).

Solution:
Incorrect: behavior: url(../../funkce/PIE.php);
Correct: behavior: url(funkce/PIE.php);

What is correct and what not is different for different people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
Incorrect: behavior: url(../../funkce/PIE.php);
Correct: behavior: url(funkce/PIE.php);

What is correct and what not is different for different people.

=> I close this topic and accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how PIE works, but did you tried this way?

```
border-top-right-radius: ??px;
border-top-left-radius: ??px;
border-bottom-right-radius: ??px;
border-bottom-left-radius: ??px;
```

Comment: I tried it, but still not work. Anyway I thank for this tip. I read somewhere about border-radius and there they wrote something like this "border-radius must be written with all corners like border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px".

Comment: I dont' think so... But anyway, try border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;

Comment: I have "border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;" in my code from start when I used PIE.

Comment: Have a look at this article http://odino.org/border-radius-and-ie-8-and-previous-yes-we-can/
I'm pretty sure this will work! If It does, let me know!

Comment: It is not working. There is only one difference between my code (include ".htc" file), but I include ".php" file and this file include".htc" file I make it because without it I muset create a .htaccess (if on server not support ".htc" file) and with include php and than include htc I make it. Simply Of course I tried include only ".htc" file but this experiment failed. When I arrive home, I'll try it again.

Comment: `"Only the shorthand version is supported"`, so this answer cannot be correct. see http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#border-radius